# How do I make a report that constantly updates when I set values?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, report

Ok so I don't really know if this exists with some package somewhere, or if I need to roll my own (which I don't really want to do). Basically what I am looking for is a reporting type system that would almost reflect Task Manager, the best example I could think of.

I have a WCF service that communicates business logic back to subscribed clients when data changes. So I would like to have that report updated whenever the event hits the client.

I have created a new .rdlc and started building the thing but it seems very cumbersome with what I am actually trying to accomplish and heavy. Are the basic reports my only options?

**Edit**

My question might be a little misleading. I am looking for an alternative if it exists for reporting that can update in a live fashion.

Thanks

**Edit 2**

I do not want to use the reports inside visual studio....I am looking for alternatives to reports. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using wsDualHttpBinding in WCF you can send your callbacks to the client.  Then your client object can fire events off that other forms or objects can subscribe to to be notified of updates.

Even if you are using traditional binding, you can still fire off events from your client object that your forms or reports can subscribe to.

**Edit:**

I'll elaborate a bit more you since you don't understand what I'm saying.

1. You appear to be using ReportViewer since you implied .rdlc in your question.  You should make that explicit, especially if it is the focus of your question.
2. You mention that your data is delivered from a WCF service.  This is an important fact when you are asking about how to update a report.
3. You said your client has subscribed to this service.  Good, we got that out of the way.
4. Your question was "is basic reports your only option?"

Therefore my answer remains, No, you can update basic reports (or any other object) very easily using events, here's how:

Once your callback gets called (or your client hits the server if you are not using dual communication) you need to fire an event that your form containing your ReportViewer object will subscribe to.  When your form receives the notice of that event, you will need to force your report to refresh itself by calling `reportViewer.RefreshReport();`

Comment: Please reread my question. I am asking for a report not suggestions for my service. Thanks!

Comment: +1 I thought this answer showed you a way to do it, you didn't mention if you did research to see if there are any alternatives? I did research and didn't find any - thus this answer seems to have value.

Comment: @meanbunny: Saw both of your comments including the one that was recently deleted.  See edit to my original answer.

Comment: After re-reading my question yet again I see why it's not being interpreted correctly. I am looking for different reports than the built in reports that are in visual studio. That's why I said in the original question I am looking for a reporting system similar to Task Manager. That's why I edited the question stating are the basics reports my only options.

Comment: I apologize my question is horrible. It's not to the point or stated very specifically to what I am looking for.

Comment: If you are just looking for an alternative Reports Engine, take a look at ActiveReports.  You have to purchase a license, but the cost is reasonable.  I use it for all of my companies reports.  You can provide them in a viewer or as PDFs, XLS, DOC, etc.  http://www.datadynamics.com/products/ActiveReports/Overview.aspx